# How to implement an inherited property in a constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance

The class `Player` herits from `Deckholder` where the property `Deck` has been declared.

```
public class Deckholder
{
    public Deck Deck { get; set; }

    public Deckholder(Deck deck)
    {
        Deck = deck;
    }
}
public class Player : Deckholder

{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Player(string name, Deck deck)
    {
        Deck = deck;
        Name = name;
        Score = 0;
    }
```

VSCode tells me, that

> No argument that fits the formal parameter "deck" from "Deckholder.Deckholder(Deck) was found."

with  red squiggles under the `Player`-constructor. But how do I fix this? I mean I do have a `Deck deck` as a parameter and I need that.

Comment: You have to call the base constructor: `public Player(string name, Deck deck) : base(deck)`.

Comment: BTW: this is not an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) but a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: @KlausGütter Ah yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the constructor of the `Deckholder`class from your constructor of your `Player` class. Use the `base` keyword for this:

```
public Player(string name, Deck deck) : base(deck)
{
    Name = name;
    Score = 0;
}
```

You don't have to assign `deck` in the `Player` class anymore, because it is done in the base constructor.